# I'm having a difficult time dynamically changing SKSpriteNodes speed values in my SpriteKit game

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

In my game I've implemented infinite scrolling platforms and a background that start from the bottom of the screen and scroll to the top. They get deleted when the reach the top of the screen and a new set appears at the bottom. My issue is adjusting the speed dynamically for all of the platforms that get spawned in. I have a system that involves a switch case that can be controlled with a UIButton and that controls the 'state' in which the platforms, background and my player node are in. This includes certain properties of the player node and how fast the the platforms and background scroll within each state of the switch case. I'm trying to use the `.speed` property of `SKSpriteNode`, however it's not working as intended. Here's a sample recreation of my switch case:

```
switch state {
case 1:
     background.speed = 1
     platform.speed = 1
case 2:
     background.speed = 2
     platform.speed = 2
}
```

With this, I can control which state of the switch case with a button and go back between case 1 and case 2. I can go to case 2 and make the speeds be 2, then if I wanted, go back to case 1 and make the speeds 1 again. So what's actually happening is that when I change the state of the switch case, the existing platform speeds don't really conform to the new speed value, only the new platforms that spawn *after* the speed value change. So what that looks like in real time is that I have platforms moving across the screen and the new ones that do conform to the new values catch up and pass the platforms that spawned *before* the new ones. I need every platform node to update in real time so there's equal spacing between each set.

With much trial and error, I'm not entirely sure what I'm missing, but if anyone has any idea of a possible solution, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with platform property and relations. What does platform property stands for? Array or just one object platform that is getting override again and again?

You should put platforms under some SKNode, and change speed of that SKNode.

So in code:

- in class where you have platforms add property `allPlatforms` of type `SKnode` and initialize it at start.
- every time you add new platform you add it under `allPlatforms` as child, so `allPlatforms.addChild(platform)`
- and when deleting, delete from allPlatforms: `platform.removeFromParent()`

And than you just change speed of `allPlatforms` instead of `platform`, and it should work, but another problem might be that it is not array, but I can't see your code so I just guess :/

Comment: I've worked a bit more on it but am still having a similar problem. Here's another post with my code and a video showing what's going on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64436047/my-skspritenode-speed-values-are-not-updating-properly