# My SKSpriteNode speed values are not updating properly

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

What I'm trying to do is update my SKSpriteNodes so I can change their scrolling speeds dynamically, however they aren't really working consistently. I didn't include the code, but I have another method with a switch case that sets the value of `platformSpeed` whenever the state is changed (in this case, the switch case is changed with UIButtons). In my code I have an `SKSpriteNode` array and a `platformSpeed` property that includes `didSet` so my value is updated properly.

In my method to create the platforms, I grouped my SpriteNodes into `platformGroup` then looped through them with `addChild()`. Not sure why it's acting this way but here's a quick video of what it looks like in action:

[demonstration clip](https://gfycat.com/unrealisticrepentantazurewingedmagpie)

So with the buttons I'm changing the switch case, and as you can see, not all of the nodes speeds are updating properly and some get faster than others and eventually pass them. I need them to stay equal distance between each other.

Now here's my code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var platformGroup = [SKSpriteNode]()
var platformSpeed: CGFloat = 1.0 {
    didSet {
        for platforms in platformGroup {
            platforms.speed = platformSpeed 
        }
    }
}

let platformTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "platform")
var platformPhysics: SKPhysicsBody!


func createPlatforms() {
    
    let platformLeft = SKSpriteNode(texture: platformTexture)
    platformLeft.physicsBody = platformPhysics.copy() as? SKPhysicsBody
    platformLeft.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    platformLeft.scale(to: CGSize(width: platformLeft.size.width * 4, height: platformLeft.size.height * 4))
    platformLeft.zPosition = 20

    let platformRight = SKSpriteNode(texture: platformTexture)
    platformRight.physicsBody = platformPhysics.copy() as? SKPhysicsBody
    platformRight.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    platformRight.scale(to: CGSize(width: platformRight.size.width * 4, height: platformRight.size.height * 4))
    platformRight.zPosition = 20
    
    let scoreNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.clear, size: CGSize(width: frame.width, height: 32))
    scoreNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: scoreNode.size)
    scoreNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    scoreNode.name = "scoreDetect"
    scoreNode.zPosition = 40

    platformGroup = [platformLeft, platformRight, scoreNode]

    let yPosition = frame.width - platformRight.frame.width

    let max = CGFloat(frame.width / 4)
    let xPosition = CGFloat.random(in: -80...max)

    let gapSize: CGFloat = -50


    platformLeft.position = CGPoint(x: xPosition + platformLeft.size.width - gapSize, y: -yPosition)
    platformRight.position = CGPoint(x: xPosition + gapSize, y: -yPosition)
    scoreNode.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: yPosition - (scoreNode.size.width / 1.5))

    let endPosition = frame.maxY + (platformLeft.frame.height * 3)

    let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: endPosition, duration: 7)
    let moveSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveAction, SKAction.removeFromParent()])
    
    for platforms in platformGroup {
        addChild(platforms)
        platforms.run(moveSequence)
    }
    
    platformCount += 1
}

func loopPlatforms() {
    let create = SKAction.run { [unowned self] in
        self.createPlatforms()
        platformCount += 1
    }
    
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.1)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([create, wait])
    let repeatForever = SKAction.repeatForever(sequence)
    
    run(repeatForever)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I can see what's going wrong. When you change `platformSpeed`, it changes the speed of all the platforms in `platformGroup`. And `createPlatforms()` is being called multiple times. Now, each time it's called you create a pair of platforms and assign these to `platformGroup`. Since you call the function multiple times, it's overwriting any existing values in the array. That's why changing `platformSpeed` only updates the speed of the latest platforms you've created---the older platforms stay the same speed because they're not in `platformGroup` anymore.

To fix this, my advice would be to have platformGroup store all the platforms currently on the screen. You could do this by changing

```swift
    platformGroup = [platformLeft, platformRight, scoreNode]
```

to something like

```swift
    let newNodes = [platformLeft, platformRight, scoreNode]
    platformGroup += newNodes
    // Alternatively, platformGroup.append(contentsOf: newNodes)
```

Now you need to make sure you're 1) only adding the new nodes to the scene, and 2) removing the old nodes from `platformGroup` when they're removed from the parent. You could do this by changing

```swift
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: endPosition, duration: 7)
    let moveSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveAction, SKAction.removeFromParent()])
    
    for platforms in platformGroup {
        addChild(platforms)
        platforms.run(moveSequence)
    }
```

to something like

```swift
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: endPosition, duration: 7)
    
    for node in newNodes {
        let moveSequence = SKAction.sequence([
            moveAction, 
            SKAction.removeFromParent(),
            SKAction.run {
                self.platformGroup.remove(node)
            }
        ])

        addChild(node)
        node.run(moveSequence)
    }
```

Now that you're keeping a track of all platforms ever made, your speed changes should be applied consistently to every platform on the screen. Hope this works!